# Azure BlobClient.beginCopy(..) error in Scheduler worker in group main failed with an uncaught exception

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-functions, cloud, azure-blob-storage

Following is my code:

```
try (CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFile.getAbsolutePath()))) {
            //List<String[]> r = reader.readAll();            
            String[] lineInArray;
            int count = 0;
            while ((lineInArray = reader.readNext()) != null) {
                String interId = lineInArray[0];
                String fileId = null;
                String mp3Name = null;
                List<Map<String, Object>> filesList = ccrDao.retrieveCallIdAndPaths(interId);
                
                for (Iterator iterator = filesList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                    Map<String, Object> map = (Map<String, Object>) iterator.next();
                    
                    fileId = map.get("C_CALL_ID")!=null?map.get("C_CALL_ID").toString():"";
                    mp3Name = map.get("C_FILENAME")!=null?map.get("C_FILENAME").toString():"";
                    
                    if(!fileId.equals("") && !mp3Name.equals("")) {
                        String blobName = fileId+"/"+mp3Name;
                        context.getLogger().info("blobName: "+blobName);
                        BlobClient sourceBlobClient = srcContainer.getBlobClient(blobName);
                        context.getLogger().info("source blob client");
                        BlobClient destBlobClient = dstnContainer.getBlobClient(blobName);
                        context.getLogger().info("destination blob client");
                        
                        if(!destBlobClient.exists()) {
                            context.getLogger().info("blobName doesnt exist :"+blobName);
                            BlobServiceSasSignatureValues sas = new BlobServiceSasSignatureValues(OffsetDateTime.now().plusHours(1), BlobContainerSasPermission.parse("r"));
                            String sasToken = sourceBlobClient.generateSas(sas);
                            context.getLogger().info("generated sas token :"+sasToken);
                            destBlobClient.beginCopy(sourceBlobClient.getBlobUrl()+"?"+ sasToken,null);
                            //destBlobClient.copyFromUrl(sourceBlobClient.getBlobUrl());
                            context.getLogger().info(interId+"copied successfully");
                        }else {
                            context.getLogger().info("blob already exists");
                        }

                    }else {
                        context.getLogger().info("No file is present");
                        
                    }

                }
                count++;
                context.getLogger().fine("Recourd Count "+count);
            }
            
        } catch (Exception e ) { //IOException | CsvException
            context.getLogger().severe("Error occured while copying the data :"+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Getting  below error on line

```
"destBlobClient.beginCopy(sourceBlobClient.getBlobUrl()+"?"+ sasToken,null);"
```

body {font-family:Arial; margin-left:40px; }img  { border:0 none; }#content { margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto }#message h2 { font-size: 20px; font-weight: normal; color: #000000; margin: 34px 0px 0px 0px }#message p  { font-size: 13px; color: #000000; margin: 7px 0px 0px0px}#errorref { font-size: 11px; color: #737373; margin-top: 41px }Service unavailable

### Our services aren't available right now

We're working to restore all services as soon as possible. Please check back soon.

0XjmzYAAAAAC2Ast2oBmIS47phNpxTuFBQk9NMDFFREdFMDIxOQA3ZGIwYWMxYy1iNzZkLTRiYTQtYTE3NS01NTgxNTUxMTEzZDU=Error in Scheduler worker in group main failed with an uncaught exception.

Comment: provide detailed error and detailed info about your STA please.

Comment: I am getting error on this line destBlobClient.beginCopy(sourceBlobClient.getBlobUrl()+"?"+ sasToken,null); its working fine in localhost

Comment: updated the error trace. its batch which is copying blob from one container to another and i am running the batch under azure function app, Hosted the batch on function app now after working successfully in localhost.

Comment: Please do not provide details in comments. Instead edit your question and provide all details there. As of now it is not clear what’s your setup and what exactly are you trying to do when getting this error.

Comment: Can you put your code inside try/catch block and log the exception you’re getting? Considering your code is working locally, I suspect some configuration issues. The exception will tell us more.

Comment: @GauravMantri - ok, my code is already in try catch block but function is terminating with 503 response. Please check question updated.

Comment: @GauravMantri : The function is terminating without caching the error/exception.

Comment: That is totally weird! Can you try something for me please? Just comment `destBlobClient.beginCopy(sourceBlobClient.getBlobUrl()+"?"+ sasToken,null);` line and log `destBlobClient`, `sourceBlobClient.getBlobUrl()` and `sasToken` and share those values. Please change the account name to some random string before sharing. Also, please tell if it is .Net? What version of SDK you're using?

Comment: @GauravMantri : Sir, I have finally found the solution, I posted the answer. Thanks a lot for your inputs. See ya.

Comment: Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. You did that. Good - and is all you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suspected the issues was not related to tier or any scaling issue. While executing my function was not showing the complete logs and my code also unable to catch the exception so I followed below steps.

1. Checked the "host" logs via Kudu -Debug Console.
2. Able to find the actual error at beginCopy() step as stated below

2021-05-31T14:37:48.513 [Information] 2021-05-31 14:37:48.494 ERROR 5820 --- [     parallel-1] reactor.core.scheduler.Schedulers        : Scheduler worker in group main failed with an uncaught exception
2021-05-31T14:37:48.513 [Information] java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: okhttp3.RequestBody.create(Lokio/ByteString;Lokhttp3/MediaType;)Lokhttp3/RequestBody;

3. After doing analysis on above error, override the okhttp version in my pom.xml by adding below dependency

```
<dependency>      
       <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>     
       <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>     
       <version>4.9.1</version>      
</dependency>
```

4. clean package and replace all the libraries with the existing one. Don't just replace one library in the function app as its dependent libraries like okio jar also has to update